# SSRS 2008 export to MS Word issue

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

I have a ssrs 2008 report which when exported to word gives all sorts of horizontal and verticals lines with data in between and also does not include the image. As an example please see the below snapshot of the original report:

<< THERE IS AN IMAGE HERE >>
[image]

And now the word export snapshot:

<< THE IMAGE IS MISSING FROM EXPORT >>
[image]

Pls. suggest

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using some type of table/tablix? It might be that you just need to set the Border Style to "None"

Comment: its already set to None. Also I have not used tablix for the above.

Comment: when the document is opened in 2007 it does not have the grid lines. It seems in 2007 "Table -> Hide Gridlines" is default option while in 2003 "Table -> Show Gridlines" is the default. Took a while to figure it out !! Silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the document is opened in 2007 it does not have the grid lines. It seems in 2007 "Table -> Hide Gridlines" is default option while in 2003 "Table -> Show Gridlines" is the default. Took a while to figure it out !! Silly.